# numpy/arrayobject.h and C extension

Tags: c, numpy, matrix

I intend to do some computation on numpy arrays in C code. Could someone please point to some document on how to extract the double* C array from a numpy.matrix object? So I could have some C code like this:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy_arrayobject.h>
static PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject *args)
{
    some_numpy_array_t *x;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &x)
        return NULL;
    double* data = x->some_function_to_get_the_raw_data();
    ...
}
```

I am looking for what type some_numpy_array_t and what function some_function_to_get_the_raw_data() should be in real code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on:

http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/python/src/python-numeric-22.0/doc/www.pfdubois.com/numpy/html2/numpy-13.html

One needs PyArrayObject and PyArray_DATA(). The latter is a macro returning void*, so

```
double* data = (double*) PyArray_DATA(x);
```

is the correct line.

Note a call to import_array() is also needed.